# Trying To Open Bitcoin Miner On Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, file-permissions

Trying to open a file, but terminal says permission denied. I think it has something to do with permission of something.

Open Terminal in the Utilities folder

type

```
cd /Applications/bfgminer-5-mac/bfgminer/bin
```

press enter then type

```
./bfgminer
```

But this does not seem to work, and it says "permission denied".

Comment: do `sudo chmod +x bfgminer` and then `./bfgminer`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the execute permissions on the file. From Terminal, type

```
chmod +x /Applications/bfgminer-5-mac/bfgminer/bin/bfgminer
```

and then try running the application again